# Какие технические требования для публикации в App Store?

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore

Обязательно ли наличие физического iOS/iPadOS устройства? Интересует именно публикация (подпись). Тестировать собираюсь на симуляторе. Кроме создания сертификатов не могу найти какие-либо инструкции, где об этом говорится.

Comment: физический девайс в любом случае нужен для создания архива приложения для заливки на аппстор

Comment: @schmidt9 создать архив можно, выбрав https://prnt.sc/uyeegk, разве не так?

Comment: [RTFM](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/submitting).

Comment: @IgorR. да вы правы

Comment: Попробуйте поискать ответ в этой инструкции, она достаточно подробная: https://livetyping.com/ru/blog/kak-vylozhit-prilozhenie-v-app-store